# How can I find a way to minimum the number of edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am thinking an algorithm to solve the problem below:

> A given graph composed of vertices and edges.
>
> There are N customers who want to travel from a vertex to another vertex.
> And each customer requirement need a directed edge to connect two vertices.
>
> The problem is how to find the minimum number of edges to satisfy all customers requirements ?

There is a simple example:

- Customer 1 wants to travel from vertex a to vertex b.
- Customer 2 wants to travel from vertex b to vertex c.
- Customer 3 wants to travel from vertex a to vertex c.

The simplest way is to give an edge for each customers:

- edge 1: vertex a -> vertex b
- edge 2: vertex b -> vertex c
- edge 3: vertex a -> vertex c

But actually there only needs 2 edges (i.e. edge 1 and edge 2) to satisfy three customer requirements.

If the number customers is large, how to find the minimum edges to satisfy all customer requirements ?

Is there a algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, every edge in graph is directed edge!
That is my fault, I should emphasize that the given graph is directed graph.

Comment: This is a problem of Transitive Reduction. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "And each customer requirement need a directed **path** to connect two vertices."  If you really meant "directed edge", then the problem is trivial, and the answer to your example problem requires all 3 edges.

Comment: I thought the problem of "Transitive Reduction" provided by user1990169 meet what I need. Thanks !!!

Comment: Actually, I just want to minimum the number of edges and make sure the reachability is unchanged.

Comment: I now know that this problem belongs to **Transitive Reduction**.

But.... I cannot find an implemented C/C++ code for this algorithm.

Comment: I now know that this problem belongs to **Transitive Reduction**.

But.... I cannot find an implemented C/C++ code for this algorithm.

Boost Library provides **Transitive Closure** but not **Transitive Reduction**. LEDA Library provides both **Transitive Closure** and **Transitive Reduction** but not free.
Any idea ??

Comment: Transitive reduction may not be the answer. If we have customer requirements like a->b, a->c, b->d, c->d, then the transitive reduction keeps all customer arcs, whereas the three arcs a->b, b->c, c->d yield as much connectivity. If we can build only arcs demanded by some customer, then we need not a transitive reduction but a minimum equivalent subgraph (NP-hard to find if there are cycles).

Comment: You can try to add all the required edges to the graph, i.e. if the customer C wants to go from A to B then add the edge AB. Then, compute the minimum spanning tree of this graph (with each edge having a weight of 1). The sum of weights will be equal to the number of edges (and it'll be the minimal number of edges).

Answer (score 0):

You can model the problem as a mixed integer program. You can define binary variables for "arc a-> b is used" and "customer c uses arc a -> b" and write down the requirements as linear inequalities. If your graph is not too large, you can solve such models in reasonable time by a mixed integer program solver (CPLEX, GUROBI, but there also free alternatives on the web).

I know that this solution requires some work if you are not familiar with linear programming, but it guarantees to find best solutions in finite time and you can probably solve it for (say) 1000 customers and 1000 arcs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have N vertices, you can always construct a solution with N (directed) edges.  Just create a directed cycle V_1 -> V_2 -> V_3 ->... -> V_N -> V_1.  You can never have directed path from every vertex V_a to every other vertex V_b with fewer edges (because you'd have a directed tree which necessarily contains a leaf).  The leaf is either un-reachable (if the edge goes from leaf out) or the leaf is a sink (can't connect to anything else) if the edge is ->leaf.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any new algorithm. You can use BFS/DFS algorithm.

```
Find if there exists any path between source and destination.
   if !true
      add a direct edge between source and destination
      count++;
return count;
```

Here the key part is instead of loop through the graph we have to loop through newly added edges.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Disjoint set data structure.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

```
while (num_edges--)
    if root(vertex_a) != root(vertex_b)
    count++
    union(vertex_a,vertex_B)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I think of the same problem for undirected edges, what we are looking for is the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST) of the original graph (constructed of all edges). The brief explanation is that for each edge E (v1 -> v2) if there is a second path to v2 from v1, there exist a cycle, and for each existing cycle there is an edge we can omit.

For finding MST of a directed graph there is [Chu–Liu/Edmonds' algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) you can use.

Note that you are assigning a weight of 1 to all of your edges.